# Safari extension: passing window object from inject script to global page

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

Is there a way to pass window object from inject script to global.html page,

I am trying to pass window as part of an object to global page, from "load" listener function, it throws type error when trying to dispatch the message.

Here is the code.

```
window.addEventListener("load", onDocLoad);

function onDocLoad()
{
    var msg = new Object();

    msg.url = window.location.href; // this all works 
    .....
    msg.win = window; // With this it throws type error on line safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("XXX",msg);
    safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("XXX",msg);  
}
```

Message dispatching works and other data can be passed without error expect for window object.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass objects like HTMLWindow as documentation says:

> Message data is not limited to a single data type; it can be Boolean, numeric, a string, an array, a RegExp object, or anything that conforms to the W3C standard for safe passing of structured cloned data. It can also be null, undefined, or left blank, in cases where the command needs no data.